# Getting error: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: python, arguments, python-multithreading

Code:

```
from re import X
import socket
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue

class Uhfthread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = True 
        self.tagJson = {}
        self.previousTag = ""
        self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.connect,args=(), daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.join()

    def connect(self):
        while self.connected:
            try:
                self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.s.connect(("192.168.1.232", 100))
                self.connected = True
                print( "connected" )
                self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.readTagOnce,args=(), daemon=True)
                self.thread.start()
                self.thread.join()
            except Exception as i:
                print(i)
                self.connected = False    
                print("connection lost... reconnecting")  
                while not self.connected: 
                    try:  
                        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        self.s.connect(("192.168.1.232", 100))  
                        self.connected = True  
                        print( "re-connection successful" )  
                    except socket.error:  
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print("uhf is not connected")

    def checksum(self,msg):
        sm = 0
        for i in range(0, len(msg)):
            sm = sm + msg[i]
        high, low = divmod(int(sm), 0x100)
        csm = (0xff - low + 1)
        return csm

    def readTagOnce(self,data):  
        try:
            while True:
                data = 0
                time.sleep(0.5)
                message = bytearray(b'\x0A\xFF\x02\x44')
                csm = Uhfthread.checksum(self,message)
                message.append(csm)
                self.s.send(message)
                msg = self.s.recv(32)
                msgStr = msg.hex()
                message = bytearray(b'\x0A\xFF\x0B\x84\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0C\x00\x20')
                csm = Uhfthread.checksum(self,message)
                message.append(csm)
                self.s.send(message)
                msg = self.s.recv(32)
                msgStr = msg.hex()
                if str(msgStr) == '0be80400000108':  
                    message = bytearray(b'\x0A\xFF\x03\x41\x10')
                    csm = Uhfthread.checksum(self,message)
                    message.append(csm)
                    self.s.send(message)
                    msg = self.s.recv(1024)
                    msgStr = msg.hex()
                    uhfTag = msgStr[14:38]
                    res = "{0:08b}".format(int(uhfTag, 16)).rjust(96, '0')
                    fasTageCheck = int(res[14:38], 2)
                    print('fastag--> ',fasTageCheck)
                    if fasTageCheck == 8907272:
                        print("FASTAG DETECTED")
                        if self.previousTag != uhfTag:
                            self.previousTag = uhfTag
                            uhfEpcId = msgStr[38:70]
                            print(uhfEpcId)
                            uhfTid = msgStr[70:118]
                            print(uhfTid)
                            uhfUserData = msgStr[118:246]
                            self.tagJson['uhfTag'] = uhfTag
                            self.tagJson['uhfEpcId'] = uhfEpcId
                            self.tagJson['uhfTid'] = uhfTid
                            self.tagJson['uhfUserData'] = uhfUserData
                            print(self.tagJson)
                            value=[uhfEpcId,uhfTid,uhfUserData]       
                            data = value
                            print(data) 
                        else:
                            print("same TAG")
                            uhfEpcId = msgStr[38:70]
                            uhfTid = msgStr[70:118]
                            uhfUserData = msgStr[118:246]
                            self.tagJson['uhfTag'] = uhfTag
                            self.tagJson['uhfEpcId'] = uhfEpcId
                            self.tagJson['uhfTid'] = uhfTid
                            self.tagJson['uhfUserData'] = uhfUserData
                            print(self.tagJson)
                            value=[uhfEpcId,uhfTid,uhfUserData]  
                            data.put(value) 
                            print(data)      
                    else:
                        print('Not a FASTAG')
        except Exception as i:
            print("uhf data not found",i)
    def WriteTag(self,data,instance):
        try:
            if self.q.empty():
                print("data not found",data)
            else:
                h=self.q.get()
                print(h)
        except:
                print("blank data sent")
        try:
            enter_record = {
            "uhfdata": self.tagJson,
            "laneNo" :"1"
            }
        except:
            print("data not found")
a=Uhfthread()
a.WriteTag()
```

Data is received from UHF reader and stored in `self.json`. When I just print without data, I get all the details from `self.json`; but not in `entryrecord()`.
I want to get the data from `self.json` and store it in `entryrecord`.
I'm getting following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-157 (readTagOnce):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kamle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\kamle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: Uhfthread.readTagOnce() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Comment: `self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.readTagOnce(),args=(), daemon=True)`

Comment: output: uhf data not found 'Uhfthread' object has no attribute 's'